# Выборка значений подзапросом

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Существует многоуровневый список этажей и кабинетов на каждом этаже в здании.
В этом списке есть этаж ID=1 и кабинет ID=2.

```
app_global_lists_choices
+----------------+----+-----------+
|      name      | id | parent_id |
+----------------+----+-----------+
|         1 этаж |  1 |    0      |
|    Кабинет УЗИ |  2 |    1      |
|    Кабинет ЭКГ |  3 |    1      |
|         2 этаж |  4 |    0      |
|    Кабинет ЛФК |  5 |    4      |
+----------------+----+-----------+
```

Подразумевается, что запрос:

```
$sql = "select name from app_global_lists_choices where id in (1,2)"
```

вернет номер этажа и название кабинета.

На деле возвращается только название первого значения (1 этаж). Второе бесследно пропадает.

Возможно ли вернуть запрос в таком виде:

```
1 этаж / Кабинет УЗИ
```

Comment: обычно кидают структуру таблиц(ы) м пару строк для примера..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При всём идиотизме решения - работать будет:

```
SELECT REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(name ORDER BY id), ', ', ' / ')
FROM app_global_lists_choices 
WHERE id IN (1,2)
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо, работает! Хотя есть одно НО! Я намерено упростил задачу, решив, что на конечный результат это не повлияет. А нет, повлияло. На самом деле описанный мной запрос является подзапросом, а значения 1,2 генерятся другим запросом. Родительский запрос "связывает" ФИО врача с кабинетом. В общем это выглядет так: SELECT REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(name ORDER BY id), ',',' / ')
FROM app_global_lists_choices 
WHERE id IN (select field_2 from app_entity_1 where id=created_by)  И вот в таком виде опять отдает только "1 этаж"